# how do I connect computer accounts at home using the same wifi network

Tags: windows-7

I have two of the same toshiba laptops and I want to connect the users on it so I can log in on the same account from any of the two laptops they are both set to home group so how do I connect them like they have it at schools how you can log in to your account from any computer

Comment: You would need a server for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure [Active Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on one of the laptops, and keep that laptop always on. On both laptops configure a company network (which would be your home network).

[Here's](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574166.aspx) the Microsoft article on how to set up ADS, this essentially includes:

- Installing Active Directory Services
- Configuring ADS

  - Setting a static IP to the ADS server
  - Pointing all computers on the network (that you want to use ADS on) to the ADS as a WINS server (done via DHCP)
  - Connecting all computers on the network (that you want to use ADS on) to the "corporate" network
- Setting up logins
- Using the logins